# How does Breeze handle database column defaults?

Tags: breeze

I can't find any info about this in the documentation, so I will ask here. How does breeze handle database column defaults? I have required columns in my database, but there are also default static values supplied for these in the database column definitions. Normally, I can insert null into these columns, and the new records will get the default. However, breeze doesn't seem to be aware of database column defaults, and the entities that have null in these columns fail validation on saving.

Thanks,
Mathias

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the edmx xml by adding *StoreGeneratedPattern = "Computed"* attribute to the column with default value in the DB.

***Edit:***
Actually, before doing editing the xml, try setting the *StoreGeneratedPattern* property to *Computed* in the model editor itself.

Answer (score 0):

### Update:

This was fixed in Breeze 1.4.6 ( or later), available now.

### Original Post:

There is currently in a bug in Breeze that should be fixed in the next release, out in about week.  When this fix gets in then breeze will honor any defaultValues it finds in the EntityFramework data model.

One problem though is while it is easy to get 'defaultValues' into a Model First Entity Framework model via the properties editor, it's actually difficult to get it into a Code First EF model, unless you use fluent configuration.  Unfortunately, EF ignores the [DefaultValue] attribute when constructing Code First model metadata.

One workaround that you can use now is to poke the 'defaultValue' directly onto any dataProperty.  Something like:

```
var customerType = myEntityManager.metadataStore.getEntityType("Customer");
var fooProperty = customerType.getProperty("foo");
fooProperty.defaultValue = 123;
```